# why I get 403 error after moving my laravel 5 app to new shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-status-code-403

I moved my laravel 5 app from VPS to shared hosting and when trying to navigate to the site url "http://website.com/app/public"
I get the following error:
[image]

and in the errors section in cpanel I see this:

> [Sat Oct 05 06:19:49.290682 2019] [core:crit] [pid 2811723:tid
>   47589351302912] (13)Permission denied: [client 198.xx.xx.xxx:41498]
>   AH00529: /home/xxxx/public_html/app/.htaccess pcfg_openfile:
>   unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that
>   '/home/xxxx/public_html/app/' is executable

update:
"/home/xxx/public_html/app/.htaccess" contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the public folder permission is not executable.
changed it to 755